# why is this angular directive only invoked once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've defined the following trivial directive

```
angular.module('my-app').directive('formPanel', function () {

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        forms: "=",
        title: "@",
        formSelect: "&"
      },
      templateUrl: 'formPanel.html'
    };
  }
);
```

the contents of the `formPanel.html` template are:

```
<h1>foo</h1>
```

If I invoke the directive 3 times like so:

```
<form-panel title="title" forms="entitledApplications" 
    form-select="goToFormDetails(selectedForm)"/>

<form-panel title="title" forms="maybeEntitledApplications" 
    form-select="goToFormDetails(selectedForm)"/>

<form-panel title="title" forms="applications" 
    form-select="goToFormDetails(selectedForm)"/>
```

The following output is rendered

```
<h1>foo</h1>
```

But I was expecting the following

```
<h1>foo</h1>
<h1>foo</h1>
<h1>foo</h1>
```

It seems that the problem occurs if the list passed to the `forms` scope attribute is empty/null, but I don't understand why.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use self closing tags for custom elements.

Your code works fine with closing tags

```
<form-panel title="title" forms="entitledApplications" 
    form-select="goToFormDetails(selectedForm)"></form-panel>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/v7qHNtsaUDnDUck3Pvsh?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Try using closing tags for your directive HTML element:

```
<form-panel title="title" forms="entitledApplications" 
   form-select="goToFormDetails(selectedForm)"></form-panel>

<form-panel title="title" forms="maybeEntitledApplications" 
   form-select="goToFormDetails(selectedForm)"></form-panel>

<form-panel title="title" forms="applications" 
   form-select="goToFormDetails(selectedForm)"></form-panel>
```